# XLSX from blob column to Oracle table

Tags: excel, oracle, plsql, blob, xlsx

I can't use e.g. external tables or any other ways to upload data than saving .xlsx file as a blob in database.

Structure of xlsx file will always be the same, is it possible to read data from blob column as a table?

Comment: Try this link https://jeffkemponoracle.com/tag/xlsx/

Answer (score 1):

The best article about it: https://jeffkemponoracle.com/tag/xlsx/.

There are several ways / tools which can help you.

If you can't use any of it, you can consider using oracle's embedded ZIP and XML tools (xlsx is the zipped folder with xml files which you can parse)

If you have Oracle APEX you can consider also this: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/aeapi/APEX_DATA_PARSER.html